# Allow widening conversions in VB

Tags: vb.net, casting, type-conversion

I have the following code I am working on in VB:

```
  Public Shared Function LoadFromSession(Of T)(sessionKey As String) As T
    Try
      ' Note: SBSSession is simply a reference to HttpContext.Current.Session
      Dim returnValue As T = DirectCast(SBSSession(sessionKey), T)
      Return returnValue
    Catch ex As NullReferenceException
      ' If this gets thrown, then the object was not found in session.  Return default value ("Nothing") instead.
      Dim returnValue As T = Nothing
      Return returnValue
    Catch ex As InvalidCastException
      ' Instead of throwing this exception, I would like to filter it and only 
      ' throw it if it is a type-narrowing cast
      Throw   
    End Try
  End Function
```

What I would like to do is throw an exception for any narrowing conversion.  For example, if I save a decimal number like 5.5 to session, then I try to retrieve it as an integer, then I would like to throw an InvalidCastException.  `DirectCast` does this fine.

However, I would like to allow widening conversions (for example, saving an integer like 5 to session, then retrieving it as a decimal).  `DirectCast` does not allow this, but `CType` does.  Unfortunately, `CType` also allows narrowing conversions, meaning that in the first example, it would return a value of 6.

Is there a way that I can achieve the desired behavior?  Perhaps by filtering the exception using VB's `Catch...When`?

Comment: Hmm, no, DirectCast only allows unboxing the value to the exact same type as the boxed value type.  There are way too many problems with this, a conversion from Integer to Single cannot work reliably for example.  Try it on the value 16777217.  Double to Decimal can't work either, not enough range.  There's no pretty solution for this, best not to do this at all.

Comment: @HansPassant I am mainly concerned with Integer to Decimal, but I suppose that I might be better off just throwing the InvalidCastException whenever DirectCast wants to throw it.

Comment: You might be able to use the GetType method to find the types involved and filter the narrowing conversion in the InvalidCastException Catch block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modulo the warning I left about this in the comment, you actually can catch the narrowing conversions that CType allows.  The Type.GetTypeCode() method is a convenience method that orders value types by their size.  Making this code work:

```
Public Function LoadFromSession(Of T)(sessionKey As String) As T
    Dim value As Object = SBSSession(sessionKey)
    Try
        If Type.GetTypeCode(value.GetType()) > Type.GetTypeCode(GetType(T)) Then
            Throw New InvalidCastException()
        End If
        Return CType(value, T)
    Catch ex As NullReferenceException
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

The only quirky one I see is that it will allow conversion from Char to Byte.

Comment: I think that this would be the best solution to my question.  However, I am going to go with your original suggestion and just throw the exception regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Since narrowing is not a got idea in general, as mentioned in the comments, it may be better to check the types and convert specific cases the way you want:

```
dim q as object = SBSSession(sessionKey)
If q.GetType Is GetType(System.Int32) Then ...
```

The problem with general narrowing and widening is that it's not a one-direction relationship. Sometimes a pair types can each contain a value that the other cannot.